# Which DVB-S satellite receivers work with Ubuntu?

Tags: tv-tuner

I would like to connect my satellite dish to my laptop. Can anybody recommend a USB DVB-S receiver that works well with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If found that the following devices are reported as working with [VDR](http://www.tvdr.de/). This usually means that they will work with other software as well:

- Hauppauge DEC 3000-s
- Hauppauge Nova USB
- Technotrend PC-Line USB
- Kathrein UFP 500
- Pinnacle PCTV 400e
- Pinnacle PCTV 450e
- Sundtek SkyTV Ultimate DVB-S/S2

I don't know, unfortunately, if you can still buy any of them. My tip is to **just try one**. Buy one locally and return it if it doesn't work. Generally speaking, many will work.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer ! :) I will search for available hardware.

Comment: Just make sure you can return it, if it doesn't work. :-)

Comment: Of course, everybody should remember such things :)